# Texture is not rendered in SFML

Tags: macos, sfml, clion

The problem is that I do not get any error and get only a black screen when I compile the code. It's worth noting that the examples in sfml website gets compiled successfully and renders the image.

** I am on macOS and using CLion.

```
void Player::initializeTexture() {
    /*
     * A texture will be loaded from a file.
     */


    if(!this->texture.loadFromFile("/Users/ismailsafwat/CLionProjects/ShapeShooters/Textures/sfmliconbig.png")){
        std::cout << "ERROR::PLAYER::INITIALIZETEXTURE::Failed to load the file!" << "\n";
    }
}
```

I tinkered alot with CMake and toolchain settings in CLion as well as reinstalled SFML, but no result yet. There are lots of support and help with Visual Studio on Windows but that doesn't help me. I have read a lot about not "mixing debug and release libs" as well but I could not figure it out anyway.

** UPDATE
The problem is solved now, and it was the order of the functions that caused the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well you cut out the most important part of loading texture.

I believe what you do is that you make new `sf::texture` and load it up.
But the problem is if you load the texture in `void Player::initializeTexture()` and not save it anywhere else it gets destroyed after the function is finished.

Comment: could you elaborate more on this?

Comment: Acctually in order to fully help you, you need to post more of your code, since as I said in my answer you had cut the most important part. It would really help if u edited your question and provided some of the Player class as well as how u load the texture.

Comment: The problem is solved now. I edited the question.